# XCode functions / parameters marked as Deprecated in docs, with no suggestion as to what to use instead

Tags: xcode

I have a slightly older project that I'm trying to bring up to date.

There are several items that are marked by xcode as Deprecated.  I, duh, want to know what to replace them with.

There is NOTHING whatsoever about this in any Apple docs (or other searches) that I can find.  They all just say "deprecated", with no "you should use this instead."

Why isn't this info front-and-center?  Doesn't the company want us developers to continue to produce products that run on their platform?

The functions I'm looking at are:

in Audio:
FindNextComponent
OpenAComponent
CloseComponent

in GL/openCL:
clCreateFromGLTexture2D
NSOpenGLPFAFullScreen
kCGLPFAFullScreen
CGLSetFullScreenOnDisplay

. . . any ideas?
thanks!
Dave

Comment: For the OpenGL full-screen stuff, the currently-recommended practice is to connect the context to a view in a window that's positioned to cover the screen. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html

Comment: Thanks; that helps a lot!  Getting closer, but still trying to figure out how to get a Context Object out of it for binding to OpenGL.  (The Audio Component stuff was trivial.)

Comment: Well, you'll have to show what you're actually doing — which objects you're creating and how — for anybody to answer with any specificity. Are you using `NSOpenGLView`? If so, it's got an `-openGLContext` method, but of course it's automatically bound to the view.

Comment: I'm currently using CGL, doing this:

Comment: oops; tried to respond with code & don't know how to put in a carriage return.  aaand, couldn't delete that reply or leave it empty, and finished editing it too late.  BUT, basically, I'm currently using CGL, with "CGLPixelFormatObj pixelObj", creating a context with that and setting it current to receive OpenGL drawing from interoperation with OpenCL.  The example you point me to uses NSOpenGLView, which has "NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat", and doesn't explicitly expose a CGLContextObj; perhaps I can just cast that NSOpenGLContext that NSOpenGLView returns from that method...?

Comment: You can edit your question to add code. As mentioned, `NSOpenGLView` has `-openGLContext` to get an `NSOpenGLContext`. That, in turn, has the `-CGLContextObj` method to get the underlying CGL object. `NSOpenGLPixelFormat` also has method to create from a `CGLPixelFormatObj` and/or to get the underlying `CGLPixelFormatObj` back from it. In other words, the Cocoa GL classes have the methods necessary to interoperate with CGL.

Comment: Ken, I've _largely_ solved this now; thank you for your help.  (Another question shall be coming soon...!)